# Map ng-model with pre poulated input value

Tags: angularjs

My requirement is to update the email id.When I enter the email manually in input box its getting mapped with ng-model and calling controller, but for prepoluted value its not getting mapped to ng-model.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-input form-control" id="defaultInputText" ng-model="details.emailAddr"  placeholder="yourname@email.com">{{accSummary.response.custEmail}}
</div>
```

I tried with `ng-bind="accSummary.response.custEmail" and value="{{accSummary.response.custEmail}}"` but no luck.

Can anybody help me what I am missing here..!! thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Set this model from controller as a prepopulated value `accSummary.response.custEmail`.

```
$scope.accSummary.response.custEmail = "YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE";
```

Set default value of that model in controller.

Comment: yes I have already done it. I am able to see the default value too, but its not getting mapped to ng-model

Comment: what you mean by mapped not getting?Do accept the answer if it's solves your problem.